# joomla update issues

Tags: joomla-3.x

[image]

Warning
JInstaller: :Install: Error SQL Can't DROP 'idx_image'; check that column/key exists
Files Update: SQL error file DB function failed with error number 1091 
Can't DROP 'idx_image'; check that column/key exists
SQL =
ALTER TABLE `#__languages` DROP INDEX `idx_image`;

Comment: What version did you update from? What database driver are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although it's strange that the `idx_image` index did not exist I wouldn't be too concerned about it. That warning is essentially telling you that Joomla tried to get rid of something but it was already gone. The Joomla update was still successful.

I recommend that you go to (from your Joomla Administrator) `Extensions` > `Manage` > `Database` and confirm that there aren't any issues. If there are, the "fix" button should fix them for you.

Otherwise, you should be OK, unless you have a high-traffic site, or are noticing slow page load. I say this because if you had one missing database index you may have other missing database indexes (and I don't think the database check I recommended you do checks for missing indexes, but I could be wrong). That could result in slow query execution.